# I need to do my operations faster

Tags: c#, matrix, time, transformation

I have a piece of code that reads points from an stl, then I have to do a transformation, aplying a transformation matrix, of this stl and write the results on other stl. I do all this stuff, but it's too slow, about 5 or more minutes.

I put the code of the matrix multiplication, it recieves the two matrix and it makes the multiplication:

```
public double[,] MultiplyMatrix(double[,] A, double[,] B)
    {
        int rA = A.GetLength(0);
        int cA = A.GetLength(1);
        int rB = B.GetLength(0);
        int cB = B.GetLength(1);
        double temp = 0;
        double[,] kHasil = new double[rA, cB];
        if (cA != rB)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("matrix can't be multiplied !!");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < rA; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < cB; j++)
                {
                    temp = 0;
                    for (int k = 0; k < cA; k++)
                    {
                        temp += A[i, k] * B[k, j];
                    }
                    kHasil[i, j] = temp;
                }
            }
            return kHasil;
        }
        return kHasil;
    }
```

My problem is that all the code is too slow, it has to read from a stl, multiply all the points and write in other stl the results, it spends 5-10 minutes to do that. I see that all comercial programs, like cloudcompare, do all this operations in a few seconds.

Can anyone tell me how I can do it faster? Is there any library to do that faster than my code?

Thank you! :)

Comment: The reason why all your commercial products can do this faster is they have huge teams of developers for those things and get a good amound of time and money. Nothing you may achieve by simply typing a few more lines of code.

Comment: How big are the arrays you are using?

Comment: my stl has 18.000 points, more or less, @Vajura , and I have to multiply each point by a 4x4 transformation matrix

Comment: For a general solution you can use threads, which should speed up your code by a factor of 3 or 4, another thing is that you can try using a math library with a inbuild alghorithm (or you make it yourself if you read how it works), i think the fastest is O(n^2.4) while yours is O(n^3). For a specific solution you need to give us more info, like what are those 4x4 matrices, check the timings of your read function if thats causing a bottle neck (probably isnt) and other things

Comment: Before you start with threading and doing all the other stuff that has been suggested here - profile your application. I doubt that matrix multiplication routine is the issue, unless you're using that for every point. Instead focus on the stuff that runs the most times, i.e. the loop for the points.

Answer (score 1):

I fond this on internet:

```
 double[] iRowA = A[i];
double[] iRowC = C[i];
for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
    double[] kRowB = B[k];
    double ikA = iRowA[k];
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        iRowC[j] += ikA * kRowB[j];
    }
}
```

then use Plinq

```
 var source = Enumerable.Range(0, N);
var pquery = from num in source.AsParallel()
             select num;
pquery.ForAll((e) => Popt(A, B, C, e));
```

Where Popt is our method name taking 3 jagged arrays (C = A * B) and the row to calculate (e). How fast is this:

```
 1.Name   Milliseconds2.Popt       187
```

Source is: [Daniweb](https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/code/355645/optimizing-matrix-multiplication)

> That's over 12 times faster than our original code! With the magic of PLINQ we are creating 500 threads in this example and don't have to manage a single one of them, everything is handled for you.

Comment: it could be the solution, but i don't understand why it use a third array called "C" if the multiplication is only of two matrix

Comment: C seems to be the result array.

Comment: one more question, "N" what is? I mean, is "the dimension of the array", but what's the dimension of the array? the 4x4 matrix? it means that N is 4?

Comment: Exactly :)

In you case N =4.

I am not the owner of Daniweb :D

Comment: Generally speaking, parallelization is not an answer on "how to make fast implementation of certain algorithm". Also suggested implementation arises many questions, like: 1. 500 threads? what? are you guys have 500 cores? 2. how big is the overhead for maintaining 500 threads? What if I multiplying matrices in series? 3. That was tested on two huge same order matrices, what if one of it is low order? ...and so on. That's why I think using (wrapper for) native BLAS implementation is much faster and better.

Answer (score 0):

You have couple of options:

1. Rewrite your code with jagged arrays (like `double[][] A`) it should give ~2x increase in speed.
2. Write unmanaged C/C++ DLL with matrix multiplication code.
3. Use third-party math library that have native BLAS implementation under the hood. I suggest [Math.NET Numerics](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/), it can be [switched](http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/MKL.html) to use [Intel MKL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl) which is smoking fast.

Probably, the third option is the best.

Comment: do you know any third-party library for that?

Comment: Or you can Use unsafe  code.

http://dev.bratched.com/en/fun-with-matrix-multiplication-and-unsafe-code/

Answer (score 0):

*Just for the records: CloudCompare is not a commercial product. It's a free open-source project. And there are no 'huge team of developers' (only a handful of them actually, doing this on their free time).*

Here is our biggest secret: we use pure C++ code ;). And we rarely use multi-threading but for very lengthy processes (you have to take the thread management and processing time overhead into account).

Here are a few 'best practice' rules for the parts of the code that are called loads of times:

- **avoid any dynamic memory allocation**
- make as less (far) function calls as possible
- always process the most probable case first in a 'if-then-else' branching
- avoid very small loops (*inline* them if N = 2 or 3)